# override JSON response using javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, api, http-post

I am trying to change the value of JSON response, i am assuming that this response is dynamic and i want to change only the value of this property *bpi.USD.description* and i want to change the  value from `United States Dollar` to `US Dollar`

Test URL: https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json

Response:

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Aug 3, 2022 20:25:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2022-08-03T20:25:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Aug 3, 2022 at 21:25 BST"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "23,342.0112",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 23342.0112
    },
    "GBP": {
      "code": "GBP",
      "symbol": "&pound;",
      "rate": "19,504.3978",
      "description": "British Pound Sterling",
      "rate_float": 19504.3978
    },
    "EUR": {
      "code": "EUR",
      "symbol": "&euro;",
      "rate": "22,738.5269",
      "description": "Euro",
      "rate_float": 22738.5269
    }
  }
}
```

And I am expecting this response:

=========================

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Aug 3, 2022 20:25:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2022-08-03T20:25:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Aug 3, 2022 at 21:25 BST"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "23,342.0112",
      "description": "US Dollar",
      "rate_float": 23342.0112
    },
    "GBP": {
      "code": "GBP",
      "symbol": "&pound;",
      "rate": "19,504.3978",
      "description": "British Pound Sterling",
      "rate_float": 19504.3978
    },
    "EUR": {
      "code": "EUR",
      "symbol": "&euro;",
      "rate": "22,738.5269",
      "description": "Euro",
      "rate_float": 22738.5269
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```js
function modifyResponse(args) {
  const {method, url, response, responseType, requestHeaders, requestData, responseJSON} = args;
      let jsonStr;
      let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
      jsonObj.bpi.USD.description = 'US Dollar';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `JSON.Parse()` you can convert it to an object, and change the properties you want.

```
let jsonStr; // this is just a stand in for the JSON string from https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json 

let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
jsonObj.bpi.USD.description = 'US Dollar';
```

Comment: By using this function in requestly app 

`function modifyResponse(args) {
  const {method, url, response, responseType, requestHeaders, requestData, responseJSON} = args;
  // Change response below depending upon request attributes received in args
  
let jsonStr; // this is just a stand in for the JSON string from https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json 

let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
jsonObj.bpi.USD.description = 'US Dollar';
}`

i am getting this error **Can't execute Requestly function**

Comment: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: your getting that error because your trying to make a synchronous request call, make the function async and then await for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough, hope this helps

you can perform this doing the following:

```js
// assuming the response has been parsed
    const responseJson = {
      "time": {
        "updated": "Aug 3, 2022 20:25:00 UTC",
        "updatedISO": "2022-08-03T20:25:00+00:00",
        "updateduk": "Aug 3, 2022 at 21:25 BST"
      },
      "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
      "chartName": "Bitcoin",
      "bpi": {
        "USD": {
          "code": "USD",
          "symbol": "&#36;",
          "rate": "23,342.0112",
          "description": "United States Dollar",
          "rate_float": 23342.0112
        },
        "GBP": {
          "code": "GBP",
          "symbol": "&pound;",
          "rate": "19,504.3978",
          "description": "British Pound Sterling",
          "rate_float": 19504.3978
        },
        "EUR": {
          "code": "EUR",
          "symbol": "&euro;",
          "rate": "22,738.5269",
          "description": "Euro",
          "rate_float": 22738.5269
        }
      }
    };
    // already parsed
    console.log(responseJson.bpi.USD);

    // assuming the response is a string dataType
    const responseJsonString = JSON.stringify({
      "time": {
        "updated": "Aug 3, 2022 20:25:00 UTC",
        "updatedISO": "2022-08-03T20:25:00+00:00",
        "updateduk": "Aug 3, 2022 at 21:25 BST"
      },
      "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
      "chartName": "Bitcoin",
      "bpi": {
        "USD": {
          "code": "USD",
          "symbol": "&#36;",
          "rate": "23,342.0112",
          "description": "United States Dollar",
          "rate_float": 23342.0112
        },
        "GBP": {
          "code": "GBP",
          "symbol": "&pound;",
          "rate": "19,504.3978",
          "description": "British Pound Sterling",
          "rate_float": 19504.3978
        },
        "EUR": {
          "code": "EUR",
          "symbol": "&euro;",
          "rate": "22,738.5269",
          "description": "Euro",
          "rate_float": 22738.5269
        }
      }
    });
    const parsedJsonResponse = JSON.parse(responseJsonString);
    parsedJsonResponse.bpi.USD.description = "US Dollar";
    console.log(parsedJsonResponse.bpi.USD);
```

Comment: Bu using this i am geeting this: 
`function modifyResponse(args) {
  const {method, url, response, responseType, requestHeaders, requestData, responseJSON} = args;
    const parsedJsonResponse = JSON.parse(responseJsonString);
    parsedJsonResponse.bpi.USD.description = "US Dollar";
}`

error: **responseJsonString is not defined**

Comment: your getting that error because your trying to make a synchronous request call, make the function async and then await for the response.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it with pure js is like this:

```
const jsonData = {"time":{"updated":"Aug 3, 2022 20:39:00 UTC","updatedISO":"2022-08-03T20:39:00+00:00","updateduk":"Aug 3, 2022 at 21:39 BST"},"disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org","chartName":"Bitcoin","bpi":{"USD":{"code":"USD","symbol":"&#36;","rate":"23,276.4380","description":"United States Dollar","rate_float":23276.438},"GBP":{"code":"GBP","symbol":"&pound;","rate":"19,449.6054","description":"British Pound Sterling","rate_float":19449.6054},"EUR":{"code":"EUR","symbol":"&euro;","rate":"22,674.6490","description":"Euro","rate_float":22674.649}}}

const checkIfIsJson = (jsonData) => {
  try{
    return JSON.parse(jsonData);
  }catch (e){
    return jsonData;
  }
}

const mutateJsonData = (jsonData) => {
  const formatedJson = checkIfIsJson(jsonData);
  if(formatedJson !== undefined && formatedJson.bpi !== undefined && formatedJson.bpi.USD !== undefined && formatedJson.bpi.USD.description !== undefined){
    formatedJson.bpi.USD.description = 'US Dollar';
  }
  return formatedJson;
}
console.log(mutateJsonData(jsonData));
```

The CheckifIsJson function will check if the json you pass it is really JSON format, if not it will pass it to JSON.

If you have the possibility to use the optional chaining operator [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) it will simplify the if like this

```
const jsonData = {"time":{"updated":"Aug 3, 2022 20:39:00 UTC","updatedISO":"2022-08-03T20:39:00+00:00","updateduk":"Aug 3, 2022 at 21:39 BST"},"disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org","chartName":"Bitcoin","bpi":{"USD":{"code":"USD","symbol":"&#36;","rate":"23,276.4380","description":"United States Dollar","rate_float":23276.438},"GBP":{"code":"GBP","symbol":"&pound;","rate":"19,449.6054","description":"British Pound Sterling","rate_float":19449.6054},"EUR":{"code":"EUR","symbol":"&euro;","rate":"22,674.6490","description":"Euro","rate_float":22674.649}}}

const checkIfIsJson = (jsonData) => {
  try{
    return JSON.parse(jsonData);
  }catch (e){
    return jsonData;
  }
}

const mutateJsonData = (jsonData) => {
  const formatedJson = checkIfIsJson(jsonData);
  if(formatedJson?.bpi?.USD?.description){
    formatedJson.bpi.USD.description = 'US Dollar';
  }
  return formatedJson;
}
console.log(mutateJsonData(jsonData));
```